# Problem using jQuery $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having problems using ajax with jQuery...

I have the following jscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('rel[close]').click(function() {
        $(this.parent).close();
    });

    $('a[rel=track]').click(function() {
        var track = this.attr('href');
        track = track.replace(/^.*#/, ''); // remove the hash part of tag id
        var data = 'track=' + track + '&user=<? echo $user; ?>',
        $.ajax({
            url: 'purchase.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#purchasePanel').html(html);
                $('#purchasePanel').show();
                }
            }
        )
    });
});
```

The debugger says theirs a problem with line `$.ajax({` Unexpected token `.`

This is the CSS:

`#purchasePanel {
    position:absolute; width:200px; height:115px; z-index:1; visibility:hidden; 
}`

With this HTML:

`<div id="purchasePanel">
<a href="Close" rel="close">Close this window</a>
</div>`

The script fails to run and no hidden DIV pops up or anything.

Any ideas why??

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: Always use `<?php` instead of `<?` - short open tags are deprecated and could be disabled!

Comment: @ThiefMaster `short_open_tags` are most certainly **not** deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You had some incorrectly placed braces.</strike> (they were just placed in a very confusing way and not properly indented)

Right before the `$.ajax` call you have a `,` instead of a `;`.

You also need to use `$(this).attr('href');` as `this` is a plain DOM object and `.attr()` need a jQuery object.

Here's the code that should be working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('rel[close]').click(function() {
        $(this.parent).close();
    });

    $('a[rel=track]').click(function() {
        var track = $(this).attr('href');
        track = track.replace(/^.*#/, ''); // remove the hash part of tag id
        var data = 'track=' + track + '&user=<? echo $user; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'purchase.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#purchasepanel').html(html);
                $('#purchasepanel').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It no longer has errors but... the script fails... any clues as to why?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the comma here instead of a semi-colon:

```
$('a[rel=track]').click(function() {
    var track = this.attr('href');
    track = track.replace(/^.*#/, ''); // remove the hash part of tag id
    var data = 'track=' + track + '&user=<? echo $user; ?>', <--------------
    $.ajax({
        url: 'purchase.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#purchasePanel').html(html);
            $('#purchasePanel').show();
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is causing the problem, but you don't have a semi-colon at the end of your ajax function call.

Comment: Missing semicolons are usually allowed in JavaScript (horrible feature IMO).

Comment: really? It seems to me that unless my js is flawless the whole script fails.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I kind of figured that wasn't it - I always use semi-colons in my code, no exceptions, so I don't know what scenarios the engine actually complains about not having one.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Wow, that's crazy. Would have been much easier if they just would have made them required all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('rel[close]').click(function() {
        $(this.parent).close();
    });

    $('a[rel=track]').click(function() {
        var track = this.attr('href');
        track = track.replace(/^.*#/, ''); // remove the hash part of tag id
        var data = 'track=' + track + '&user=<? echo $user; ?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'purchase.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#purchasePanel').html(html);
                $('#purchasePanel').show();
                }
        });
    });
});
```